# Reverse Levenshtein distance

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

In levenshtein distance you ask the question, given these two strings, what is their levenshtein distance. How would you go about taking a string and a levenshtein distance and generating all the strings within that levenshtein distance. (It would also take in a character set). So if i pass in a string x and a distance d. then it would give me all the strings within that edit distance, including d-1 and d-2....d-n; (n < d).

Expected functionality:

```
>>> getWithinDistance('apple',2,{'a','b',' '})
['applea','appleb','appel','app le'...]
```

Please note that the program is able to produce `app le` as space is included in the character set.

Comment: i've tried adding random characters to random positions, but it doesn't serve..

Comment: This question should get more votes, it's an interesting not duplicate question.

Answer (score 7):

There's a data structure that does this called the [Levenshtein automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_automaton). You construct it from a set of strings (which may have only one member) and a fixed distance *k*, and then you can query it for all strings with distance at most *k* of any of the strings it stores. A Python implementation is discussed [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata).

Alternatively, you can do a depth-limited search with backtracking for such strings.

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi: posted a link to a blog post discussing the implementation.

Comment: the site seems to have some errors, when i try the code, it says that NFA is not recognized