# Returning a list of fuzzy matches for a given string in Python?

Tags: python, string, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I've seen a lot of ways of checking if two given strings are fuzzy matches, but I want to create a list of potential fuzzy matches for one given string so I can search through a huge list for them.

The purpose of my code is to see if a given location is in the Geonames database. I have a list of 2,358,121 location names in Geonames. When I had a smaller subset of location names to search through, I iterated through the list of names, calculated the Levenshtein distance between the given location and each name with a function from the NLTK metrics module, and appended the name to a list of fuzzy matches if the Levenshtein distance was less than or equal to 1. For the larger list, this implementation is far too slow, so I'd like to instead be able to create a list of strings that have a Levenshtein distance less than or equal to 1 from the given location and check if any of these are in the list of Geonames location names.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
def fuzzysearch(givenloc, geonames):
    fuzzymatch = []
    for name in geonames:
        if metrics.edit_distance(name, givenloc) <= 1:
            fuzzymatch.append(name)   
    return fuzzymatch
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: The best way to do this is going to be with SOUNDEX (or similar), I imagine. You will still want to check the Levenshtein distance, but you will have a much smaller pool of candidates. I did something very similar for a spelling corrector for an HTML help system in JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse Levenshtein distance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239530/reverse-levenshtein-distance)

Comment: I think the post about [Levenshtein Automata](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata) linked from the answer to the mentioned duplicate should answer your question. I tend to agree with @kindall though, edit distance alone is probably too simplistic for good results.

Answer (score -1):

You could maybe narrow down the list by either filtering out all those that don't match the first letter, or maybe even normalizing each entry (by removing all non-letter characters and punctuation) and matching that on a first run, then doing the full fuzzy match on the reduced set.